# Return model from async task after call to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a web api which I'm calling (this is working correctly)

I call this like so

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var mod = Checksomething();
        return View();
    }

    public async Task Checksomething()
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserLogin { EmailAddress = "SomeEmail@Hotmail.com", Password = "bahblah" }));
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:28247/api/UserLoginApi2/CheckCredentials", content);

            var value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // I need to return UserProfile

            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile[]>(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My web api passes back a model called UserProfile, I'm having great difficulty trying to return data back to the Index controller, would someone please enlighten me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your method signature to use the generic version of Task

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    UserProfile[] profiles = await Checksomething();

    if (profiles.Any())
    {
          var user = profiles.First();
          string username = user.FirstName;

          // do something w/ username
    }
    return View();
}

public async Task<UserProfile[]> Checksomething()
{
    try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserLogin { EmailAddress = "SomeEmail@Hotmail.com", Password = "bahblah" }));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:28247/api/UserLoginApi2/CheckCredentials", content);

        var value = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // I need to return UserProfile

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfile[]>(value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

The returned Task will be unwrapped and your caller will be given the Result of the Task, which in this case will be `UserProfile[]`

Comment: in my index I get an error under UserProfile[] it says can't convert system source type Threading.thread.Tasks.task<ProjectWebApi.Models.UserProfile> to target type ProjectWebApi.Models.UserProfile

Comment: That doesn't work either I now get the following error on the index action result the async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

Comment: Your action is `public async Task<ActionResult> Index()`?

Comment: didn't notice you made a modification that changed fixed that error, but now i get an error on checksomething it says member with the same signature is already declared

Comment: That means you have two methods with the same signature. Rename one of the duplicate methods

Comment: Sorry had a method right at the bottom of my page hidden from site, its working now, but in the index method we do UserProfile[] profiles = await CheckSomething() when they returns how do I reference the users name as I want to say profiles.Firstname but the syntax helper doesn't show any variables

Comment: If an array is coming back, and only 1 user is in it, you can do `var user = profiles.FirstOrDefault().FirstName` to access the first item in the array. Make sure and check for null though. If the collection is empty, user will be null.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to grab the user. You should brush up on C# and .net though if you are unfamiliar with using collections. There are some great resources at http://MicrosoftVirtualAcademy.com to help out